# Is it okay to ask users to accept the answer that works for them?

Tags: discussion, answers, accepted-answer

Looking at questions, I found out that most questions don't have accepted answers. Is it okay to ask the OP (in a comment) to accept the answer that works for them?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Please do not do this.** Unfortunately, the persistence of these "gentle reminders" starts to accrue into a type of system-wide harassment — so we generally ask users to forgo the activity completely. **We've already added reminders to the system interface** to prompt  users to accept answers when warranted. But accepting an answer is a completely voluntary activity, and it is up to the user to decide when (and if) an answer should be accepted at all.

If this were only an occasional nudge, we'd probably just leave them as a helpful reminder towards a feature they may simply be unaware of. But as the sites start to fill with them, it becomes unwelcoming as the noise and harassment level of this feature starts to outweigh its benefits. I'd just leave it alone.

Answer (score 10):

In my opinion, today is way too early in this site's life to ask anyone to accept an answer.  None of the questions are old enough yet.  We want to encourage multiple/alternate/better answers.  It is really up to the question asker's discretion when it is time to accept an answer, and I bet that just about everyone involved in the private beta is familiar with how a Stack Exchange site works.

Comment: I agree with this. I haven't accepted any answers yet for my questions. Not because I haven't gotten any good answers, but I want to encourage others to post answers. When a question is marked as solved, users are less inclined to chip in. I like to give it a few days before I pick one

Comment: @JamesJenkins Agreed. But it's too early for me to tell you that you need to accept an answer on your question.

Comment: But if you don't accept an answer. Users that have been rep capped cannot have more than 200 rep (Remember the site must have at least 3 users with 3000+ rep at the end of beta)

Comment: @PreciousTijesunimi The end of beta in a three months, at least (most likely more). We already have around five users earning around 200 rep per day, so I wouldn't worry much.

Answer (score 5):

See main meta:

- [Do you feel dirty if you nudge new users to accept your answer when they indicate you've answered their question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14994/do-you-feel-dirty-if-you-nudge-new-users-to-accept-your-answer-when-they-indicat)
- [Asking for someone to accept your answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88535/asking-for-someone-to-accept-your-answer)

Since this is a new site in beta, it could be considered by some to be acceptable (only during this time) to pressure to get answers accepted, but

1. give it a day or two to let people consider if those really are the correct answers

   - I know I deliberately haven't selected any for mine
2. once the answer is accepted, take responsibility for cleanup. Make certain you

   - delete your request comment
   - flag any direct response comment as obsolete

Granted, if this is the course you choose to take, you need to realize the noise and atmosphere your comments will create.

Note that my recommendations differ in this regard to those of traditional moderation, but I expect those who follow my suggestions to be responsible in their use of my suggestions.